# Create a function that counts words/strings in a list of a specific length - Python 3

Tags: python

Trying to create a word counting function that will count how many words of a given length are in a list.

```
my_list =['full', 'hello', 'light', 'too', 'wise']
```

If I wanted to search that list for 4 letter words...I was thinking:

```
def word_count(list, length):
    count = 0
    if len(list) == 3: #I know this is wrong 
                       #it's just an example of what I was thinking
    count += 1
    return count
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: hi @matt-m , have you tested your code before submitting it? It is always good to test it before asking for help.

Comment: Yes sorry I will do that in future. I tried a bunch of different things but just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
def countWordlen(lst):
    count = 0
    for i in lst: # loop over the items of the list
        if len(i) == 3: # if the len the items (words) equals 3 increment count by 1
            count = count + 1
    return count
lst =['full', 'hello', 'light', 'too', 'wise']
countWordlen(lst)

OUT: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Try that, it's more Pythonic:

```
def word_count(word_list, word_length):
    return len(filter(lambda x: len(x) == word_length, word_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

@Mbruh you were almost there,you just need to loop through the whole list like

```
 my_list =['full', 'hello', 'light', 'too', 'wise']
 def word_count(list, length):
     count=0
     for word in list:
         if len(word)==length:
            count=count+1
     return count
word_count(my_list,4)
2
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a mind blank about iterating through a list with a loop.

Comment: Don't do this way btw. This is very inefficient.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov dont just say its inefficient...support your idea with examples...so we can learn from your expertise...beside..this follow what he was trying to do

Comment: First of all PEP8 is not used at all and reserved words are used. Secondly the whole function could be written like this `def word_count(word_list, word_length): return len(filter(lambda x: len(x) == word_length, word_list))` which saves unnecessary variable definitions and scopes.

Comment: so the problem with it is doesnt follow the PEP8? extra variable?count ,list ?your answer has the same variable .. which reserved word?check the argument in your answer if you are talking about reserved words...?beside this is his example..it follows what he wishes to achieve...though showing him the best way to do things is good..but again...one should not  just say something with no valid argument

Comment: this is the result of your answer with timeit 100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00835 usec per loop and this is mine.,...100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00886 usec per loop yours is faster..and talking about best practice...comprehension and lambda are better used while building new containers...not for counting..